# jersey encoded string as @pathParam resource is not passed

Tags: java, jersey-2.0

I have a resource which defined :

```
@Path("/customer/{customerId}")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response getLocationsByAccount( @QueryParam("page") Integer page,
                                      @QueryParam("per_page") Integer pageSize,,@PathParam(value = "customerId") String customerId);
```

When i am trying to do :

```
 curl 'http://localhost:8080/path/customer/1?page=1%26per_page=100'
```

everything works .

Now I would like to get the customerID as an encoded value , meaning :

```
curl 'http://localhost:8080/path/customer/jgLiFuOi%2F0dTMbssRcfNvQ%3D%3D?page=1&per_page=22'
```

i am getting resource not found .

What am I doing wrong .

Answer (score 0):

This works for me on Glassfish:

```
@Path("path")
public class Resource {
  @GET
  @Path("/customer/{customerId}")
  public String getLocationsByAccount(@QueryParam("page") Integer page,
        @QueryParam("per_page") Integer pageSize,
        @PathParam(value = "customerId") String customerId) {
    return customerId;
  }
}
```

Request:

```
curl --noproxy localhost, "http://localhost:8080/path/customer/jgLiFuOi%2F0dTMbssRcfNvQ%3D%3D?page=1&per_page=22"
```

Response:

```
jgLiFuOi/0dTMbssRcfNvQ==
```

So it does not look like you are doing anything wrong.